# How do I get my success message to show after ajax submitting form in Jquery ui-tab

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have form on a jQuery ui-tab, which loads data onto a list displayed on the same ui-tab. I have managed to get the data loaded, and the display to return to same tab for a further item to be entered. However depending on the sort order of the list the new item is not always visually obvious, I want to fade in a message, but I can't get it to work along with returning to the same tab without a manual page refresh.
I have attached both the scripts I am trying to use.

Script A

```
<script> // this one loads data perfectly but no success message appears
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#addtodoitem").live( 'submit' , function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) { 
                $('.ui-tabs-panel:visible').html(data);
                $('.itemadded').fadeIn(1000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
           };       
        });
    });
});
```

Script B

```
<script>    //this one shows the message and loads the data, but it also loads another 
        //copy of ui-tabs overlapping the original
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#addtodoitem').ajaxForm(function(data) { 
        $('.ui-tabs-panel:visible').html(data);
        $(".itemadded").fadeIn(1000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
    }); return false;  
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabs_5" class="tabs">

<h2 id="todo5" class="tablecaption">Add To-do</h2>

<p>To raise a new issue please enter the description of the issue below.</p>

    <form id="addtodoitem" class="todo" method="post" action="todo_do.php?do=<?=$todo_do != '' ? "edit&to_id={$_GET['to_id']}" : 'add'?>&pub=1&site_ref=NA">
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="status" id="status">
        <textarea name="todo" id="todo" placeholder="To raise a new issue, please type the details of the issue here"><?=$todo_free_text?></textarea> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
    </form>

<h2 class="tablecaption itemadded">Thank you, your item has been added to the list.</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to a satisfactory solution by using a separate refresh  link button and php page to cause the refresh after posting so the script is so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addtodo').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($('#todo').val()!="")
            {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'todo_do.php',
                data: { 'status': $('#status').val(),
                        'todo': $('#todo').val()
                    },
                success: function(data){
                        $('.itemadded').slideDown(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
                        $('.refreshtodo').slideDown(500);
                        $('#addtodoitem')[0].reset(); 
                        $('#tabs > ul').tabs({selected: 5 });
                    }
                });
            }
            else{$('.nothing').slideDown(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500)}
        });
    });
```

and the extra php page just contains

```
<?
header("Location: resident.php#tabs_5");
?>
```